# pass data from one screen and retrieve data from mysql in another screen and display in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-intent

I'm new to android and I'm doing a project in which I have a grid view with Image and text. When I press any particular image, I want it to go to another page and retrieve data from database and display it in that screen.

My php code works fine. But there is some problem with the java code.If I run it, I got unfortunately DemoGridView(my app name) stopped.

This is my code:

```
GridViewImageTextActivity.java


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gridview_image_text_example);

        CustomGridViewActivity adapterViewAndroid = new CustomGridViewActivity(GridViewImageTextActivity.this, gridViewString, gridViewImageId);
        androidGridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view_image_text);
        androidGridView.setAdapter(adapterViewAndroid);
        androidGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int i, long id) {
                Intent s = new Intent(GridViewImageTextActivity.this, DisplayStateWise.class);
                s.putExtra("stateValue",gridViewString[+i]);
                startActivity(s);
            }
        });
```

Config.java

```
public class Config {

    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://demoprojects.000webhostapp.com/getData.php?State=";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_STATE = "State";
    public static final String KEY_C = "Catagory";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";

}
```

DisplayStateWise.java

```
public class DisplayStateWise extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textViewResult;
    private ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_states);

        String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stateValue");

        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL+data;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(DisplayStateWise.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){
        String Name="";
        String State="";
        String Catagory = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            Name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            State = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_STATE);
            Catagory = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_C);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+Name+"\nAddress:\t" +State+ "\nVice Chancellor:\t"+ Catagory);
    }
}
```

display_states.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".DisplayStateWise" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >
</ListView>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.swathi.demogridview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".GridViewImageTextActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DisplayStateWise"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm really new to android and I'm not sure what is the problem with this code. Thank you all in advance for your help.

This is what I got in logcat

```
09:46:29 NullPointerException: Error executing task com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewForm$$Lambda$193/557090381@475c7540
```

Comment: can you share logcat error screen..to find which exception occurred during execution

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: Find your textViewResult id in DisplayStateWise.java

Comment: In xml you used listview and in java you used textview so change it

Comment: also just a suggestion try using retrofit library in place of Volley, you will be surprised at the speed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Krupa Thanks for poiting out at that error. I changed my xml accordingly but still I get NullPointerException.

Comment: @JohnJoe I read the answers for the above question, but I'm not able to rectify my error.

Comment: Find your textview id in java file